# Jruby NoSuchMethodError: org.jruby.RubyClass.defineMethod

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

#### Environment

- JRuby version :
  jruby 9.0.0.0 (2.2.2) 2015-07-21 e10ec96 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.65-b01 on 1.8.0_65-b17 +jit [linux-amd64]
- Java version
  ➜  trunk java -version
  java version "1.8.0_65"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
- Operating system and platform

  ➜  trunk `uname -a`
  Linux swapnil-Lenovo-Z50-70 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

  ➜  trunk `lsb_release -a`
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
  Release:    15.10
  Codename:   wily

Relevant info:

- [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/swapnilabnave/7a545cda3f8d6e97297c), [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/swapnilabnave/19b5826c48484da55234)
- Application/framework version: rails 3.2.22.1
- [Environment variables](https://gist.github.com/swapnilabnave/9f6b403c76a1bf3fcb78)

#### Expected Behavior

`rails c` should start a rails console

#### Actual Behavior

Exception : `LoadError: load error: hpricot_scan -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jruby.RubyClass.defineMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jruby/runtime/callback/Callback;)V`

```
➜  trunk rails c
/home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/prawn-core-0.8.4/lib/prawn/core.rb:34: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
LoadError: load error: hpricot_scan -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jruby.RubyClass.defineMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jruby/runtime/callback/Callback;)V
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
  block in require at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
   load_dependency at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
           require at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
             <top> at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/hpricot-0.8.6-java/lib/hpricot.rb:20
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   block in (root) at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1560
  block in require at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1560
           require at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72
           require at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
             <top> at /home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0@JayApp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
             <top> at /home/swapnil/Rails/Lab/MA-JRuby/trunk/config/application.rb:15
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
             <top> at script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 1):

Hpricot has not been updated in many years and appears to be using APIs we removed in either JRuby 1.7 or JRuby 9k. It will need to be updated and re-released, or you'll need to use something else.